# Spark monotonically_increasing_id gives some duplicates row after passed to a UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a UDF:

```
val convert = udf((input:Int) =>  {input + 1})
```

The original UDF does a more complicated computation, but for example here I guess that UDF is enough.

Then I do this to my data frame:

```
.withColumn("id",convert(monotonically_increasing_id))
```

Then I tried:

```
spark.sql("select * from mytable where id>400 and id < 500").show(1000)
```

Somehow I saw more than one row with the same id. The id seems to wrap around and therefore I get 4 times for each number between 400 and 500.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is due to integer overflow as `monotonically_increasing_id` returns a `Long`, in which case switching your UDF to the following should fix the problem:

```
val convert = udf((input: Long) => input + 1)
```

Comment: This is not so much a possibility as it is a certainty.  `monotonically_increasing_id` encodes the partition id in the upper 31 bits ([see doc here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@monotonically_increasing_id():org.apache.spark.sql.Column)).

Comment: @Joe Pallas, thanks for the link.  Without looking at the OP's actual duplicated data, I can only assert integer overflow a possible cause leading to the reported duplicate problem.  The term `possibility` here isn't about the fact that `monotonically_increasing_id` returns a value beyond `Int` range.